# Tight asymptotic of brute-force algorithm for creating matrix

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

Consider the following problem:

Given an array R of n elements, construct a matrix M such that M[x,y] = ∑<sub>k=x...y</sub> R[k]

I need to calculate the tight asymptotic bound... e.g. Θ(algorithm)

I believe this is O(n³) as you have two nested for loops, each with n operations, and then in the inner for loop you do up to n additions over the array R to generate the sum that is inserted into M[x,y].

Is my intuition here correct? How would I rigorously prove this?

Comment: I do not understand what is the sum `∑k=x...y R[k]`, could you detaild a bit more what you have to include in each index?

Comment: Hi Javi, Yes sorry I can't get the notation right on stackoverflow. The sum starts at k=x and goes up to k = y and sums the value of R[k] (the value of the element in R at index k). Does that help?

Comment: Yep, so you are summing up all the elements of R between X and Y indices. What happens when Y > X? Sum from Y index to X index?

Comment: Do you mean when X > Y? i.e. when the sum starts at an index greater than the index it finishes? If so -- in that case, the result is 0.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant that. Ok then I will write my answer :) - Somebody did it first.

Comment: Does my answer replies to your question >

Comment: This wouldn't, by any chance, be related to Q1.2 of Stanford's CS161 problem set due tomorrow, would it? http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs161/hw1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can do in `O(n²)` with only two nested loops, by taking the memorized solution of `∑k=x…(y-1)` in the row above:

```
for x from 1 to n, y from 1 to n
    if (y < x)
        M[x,y] = 0
    else if (y == x)
        M[x,y] = R[y]
    else
        M[x,y] = M[x,y-1] + R[y]
```

Comment: Or are you only interested in the complexity of the dumb, "brute-force" algorithm?

Comment: I had that in mind :) I would say that the if is `y < x`, and when `y==x` then the result is just `R[y]` (or `R[x]`)

Comment: You're right! I always make off-by-one errors when being confronted with the mathematical sum notation or one-based indexing :-/